# NoMethod error on new DB column on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an app on heroku to which I recently added a db column. Migration was run, application was restarted but still every now and then I get a `NoMethod` error on calling this columns method.

I'm puzzled because when I try to replicate the error on rails console on heroku everything seems ok. Even when I load up URLs which are causing the errors on production everything seems ok.

My first bet was that one of the dynos is not restarting correctly. Any ideas?

Line triggering the exception

```
if @company.ip_allowed_cookie
```

Error Message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `ip_allowed_cookie' for #<Company:0x007fb78394baa0>
```

Migration File:

```
class AddIpAllowedCookieToCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :companies, :ip_allowed_cookie, :boolean
  end
end
```

IRB:

```
irb(main):004:0> Company.columns.last
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007f2003ab20c8 @array=false, @name="ip_allowed_cookie", @cast_type=#<ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean:0x007f2003946a18 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=nil>, @sql_type="boolean", @null=true, @default=nil, @default_function=nil>

irb(main):001:0> Company.first.ip_allowed_cookie
=> nil
```

Comment: Can you share your error and migration file here?

Comment: Could be a typo somewhere - more details on which view this error occurs, or which action. please post the relevant detail like @ChetanMehta has suggested and i'm sure this can be very quickly resolved.

Comment: @ChetanMehta I added the missing details

Comment: Done rake db:migrate

Comment: Done `rake db:migrate`  For all intents and purposes the column is visible to the app hence my WTF when it fails every now and then

Comment: Which line gets you this error?

Comment: @ChetanMehta added the line in the original message body

Comment: Might be two possible reason:
Heroku not restarted properly
Migration might failed on heroku

Comment: migration ran fine, the `irb` line shows that the app recognises the column. As for the restart I will talk to heroku support

Answer (score 0):

`heroku run rake db:migrate` should do the trick ;)

Comment: "Migration was run, application was restarted but still ..."